# Fancybox hash tag linking to iframe and images

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

Im using Fancybox and have been searching for ways to add hash links to the URL.
A very similar question was asked here: http://bit.ly/IMIh6D, and this is a great work around, although ive only got it to work for inline content. I somehow need to be able to link a unique URL to iframe content (youtube videos) and images that pop-up in the fancybox lightbox. Any suggestions would be great!

Cheers!

Comment: Please refer to this code http://jsfiddle.net/f2fRM/2/show